# How can I change string into float list and 'n' of n dimensional list?

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

I have a code like this list,

```
['11,2019','12,2019']
```

I tried to use numpy and hopefully want to get result

```
array([[[11],[2019]],[[12],[2019]]])
```

I tried reshape code in numpy,

```
arr1= arr.reshpae(-1,1),
```

but it show me just this result

```
array([['11,2019'],['12,2019']])
```

not changing the type, string into float or int.

in the list step, I tried to change the type before start numpy step.

```
import numpy as np

arr1=int(arr)
```

but it shows me 
TypeError : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

I hope change the one dimensional list into two dimensional list by dividing each element in numpy

```
['11,2019','12,2019']  ->  array([[[11],[2019]],[[12],[2019]]])
```

Comment: `int` is a python function to create one integer..  You need to split those strings on the commas.

Answer (score 2):

I made a fairly heavily commented solution for OP to consider. Basically, you `split` the `str` items by a comma, `map` it to an `int`, append it to a `list`, then convert it to a `numpy` array.

```
input_list = [ '11,2019', '12,2019' ]

# initialize variable for storing the result
output_list = []

# loop through every item in the input list
for item in input_list:

    # split each item of list by comma
    split_str = item.split( ',' )

    # convert split list of strings to int
    split_int = list( map( int, split_item ) )

    # store result to variable
    output_list.append( split_int )

# convert list to numpy (optional)
output_array = numpy.array( output_list )
```

Comment: Nice and noob-friendly. But consider dropping the int conversion which is unnecessarily complicated. Much easier to let numpy do it: `np.array(output_list, dtype=int)` will convert to int if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over elements of the initial list and use split function on each one of them in order to turn them into 1d lists and add them to an output 2d list:

```
import numpy as np

arr1d = ['11,2019','12,2019']
arr2d = [] #create an output list
for el in arr1d:
    #for each element in the 1d list
    #split that element into a 1d array and add to the 2d array
    arr2d.append(el.split(','))
#convert into a numpy array if that's necessary
output = np.array(arr2d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
a=['11,2019','12,2019']
d=np.array(list((map(lambda y:[[int(y.split(',')[0])],[int(y.split(',')[1])]],a))))
print(d)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[[  11]
  [2019]]

 [[  12]
  [2019]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three options (assuming you really mean 2D array).

```
inp = ['11,2019','12,2019']
```

1. Shortest, but will eventually stop working, once the `matrix` class is removed from `numpy`:

```
np.array(np.matrix(';'.join(inp)))
# array([[  11, 2019],
#        [  12, 2019]])
```

#### 2. This is what you should use:

```
np.array([l.split(',') for l in inp], int)
# array([[  11, 2019],
#        [  12, 2019]])
```

We use a list comprehension to split each string at the comma. The second argument to `np.array` is the `dtype`; we use that to tell numpy that the input elements (which are strings) should be interpreted as ints.

3. This lets python parse the strings into tuples of ints. Works but a bit overengineered.

```
import ast
np.array([ast.literal_eval(l) for l in inp])
# array([[  11, 2019],
#        [  12, 2019]])
```

PS: If you really want what you have typed you have to append `[..., None]` to the above, for example:

```
np.array([l.split(',') for l in inp], int)[..., None]
# array([[[  11],
#         [2019]],
# 
#        [[  12],
#         [2019]]])
```

Comment: You missed a couple :)   `np.genfromtxt(inp, delimiter=',', dtype=int)`; `np.stack(np.char.split(inp, ',')).astype(int)`

Comment: @hpaulj Ouch! The second one is nasty! But why not post the first? I actually think it could be argued to be the "correct" way of doing it.